# Usage of template type to call constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, constructor

I have a (predesigned and unchangeable) abstract factory that I need to work with. Usage is to create a specific type of message that is later sent to a server. It requires a message id to work.

Example:

```
int messageID = 1000;
StartServerMessage *startServer = (StartServerMessage*)ServerAbstractFactory::CreateObject(messageID);
```

There are really *lots* of different messages and I wonder, if it possible to make a short and elegant approach on creating an instance of each message type.
Currently I call manually for each type something like this:

```
//I know at this point i want an IntegrityCheckMessage
int messageID = 2050;
IntegrityCheckMessage* message = (IntegrityCheckMessage*)ServerAbstractFactory::CreaterObject(messageID);
```

I tried to make something like that:

`auto* message = (auto*)ServerAbstractFactory::CreateObject(messageID);`

But it seems "auto is not allowed" here.
Each message derives at least from abstract class `ServerMessage`. Some special messages derive from more than this class.

I somehow know I need templates here, but cant think of any way to use them  without calling the constructor of the template class (which seems to be not allowed in c++14)

Does anybode know a way to deal with this without implementing a single method for each message type?

Using Windows 10 64bit with Visual Studio 2015 and C++14

Cheers

Comment: How can a cast to `auto*` possibly work? What type do you want to end up with? The compiler cannot read your mind.

Comment: Did you mean `auto message = (IntegrityCheckMessage*)ServerAbstractFactory::CreateObject(messageID);`?